# gap statistics LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to find the gap statistics of my clusters like this:

```
from gap_statistic import OptimalK

# creat function
def KMeans_clustering_func(X, k):
    
    # Include any clustering Algorithm that can return cluster centers
    
    m = KMeans(random_state=11, n_clusters=k)
    m.fit(X)
    
    # Return the location of each cluster center and the labels for each point.
    return m.cluster_centers_, m.predict(X)

# create a wrapper around OptimalK to extract cluster centers and cluster labels
optimalK = OptimalK(clusterer=KMeans_clustering_func)

# run optimal K on the input data (subset_scaled_interim) and number of clusters

n_clusters = optimalK(X, cluster_array=np.arange(2, 21))
```

I encounter this error:

```
inAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [211], in <cell line: 19>()
     15 optimalK = OptimalK(clusterer=KMeans_clustering_func)
     17 # run optimal K on the input data (subset_scaled_interim) and number of clusters
---> 19 n_clusters = optimalK(X, cluster_array=np.arange(2,25))
     20 print('Optimal clusters: ', n_clusters)
     22 # Gap Statistics data frame

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gap_statistic/optimalK.py:134, in OptimalK.__call__(self, X, n_refs, cluster_array)
    131     engine = self._process_non_parallel
    133 # Calculate the gaps for each cluster count.
--> 134 for gap_calc_result in engine(X, n_refs, cluster_array):
    135 
    136     # Assign this loop's gap statistic to gaps
    137     gap_df = gap_df.append(
    138         {
    139             "n_clusters": gap_calc_result.n_clusters,
   (...)
    147         ignore_index=True,
    148     )
    149     gap_df["gap_k+1"] = gap_df["gap_value"].shift(-1)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gap_statistic/optimalK.py:361, in OptimalK._process_with_joblib(self, X, n_refs, cluster_array)
    356     raise EnvironmentError(
    357         "joblib is not installed; cannot use joblib as the parallel backend!"
    358     )
    360 with Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs) as parallel:
--> 361     for gap_calc_result in parallel(
    362         delayed(self._calculate_gap)(X, n_refs, n_clusters)
    363         for n_clusters in cluster_array
    364     ):
    365         yield gap_calc_result


LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I tried running the code and it looks ok. can you share with is `X` in your code? Or try setting `X = np.random.uniform(0,1,(500,5))` to test it

Comment: Where exactly? Please post the full error trace - see how to create a [mre].